# Colspan for textarea not working

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC project , colspan for textarea not working it ignore the colspan="2" attrbuite

CSS

```
  table {
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }
    td {
        position: relative;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    td {
        left: 10px;
    }
        td:first-child {
            left: 0px;
        }
        td:nth-child(3) {
            left: 20px;
        }
```

View

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="wizard">


    <div >
        <div>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.project.Title, "Project title", new { @style = "display:inline-block" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.project.Title})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.project.Title)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.project.Year, "Year",new { @style = "display:inline-block" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.project.Year)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.project.Year)

                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  colspan="2">
                        <label>Abstract</label><span style="color:red">    *</span>
                        <textarea  class="form-control" rows="6" name="SPAbstract" required>@ViewBag.abs</textarea>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**screenshot for the page**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f5pu9e6p5q933td/temp.png?dl=0

**Note**: sorry I have included the link because I have not reached 10 points so I can not insert an image

Comment: Check you css for the `textarea` (you probably have a `max-width` set)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke no I don't have I have included all my css in the question

Comment: So you are not using the default `Site.css` file or any other css files in your view or layout? Use your browser tools to inspect the css for your `<textarea>` (and you have included `bootstrap.min.css`!)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I found this in Site.css when I removed It working correctly thanks input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}

Comment: Exactly :) Just remove it if you want to to be 100% width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in Site.css when I removed It working correctly

```
input, select, textarea { max-width: 280px; }
```